# How can I access an elements(edge) rstyle property when property 'rstyle' does not exist on type 'EdgeSingular' using strict typing?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to manually set the X position of a target node that has a connected edge in a Cytoscape diagram that includes the width of the edge label.

My edge label has been rotated by -90 degrees and wraps at 400 pixels, I know for one line of text the width will be about 22 pixels but the length of the text within the label will vary so my edge labels will have more than one line.
The edge does contain the rstyle property from which I can get useful values like labelHeight and labelWidth but I am using TypeScript strict type safety and the Type definitions for Cytoscape.js specifically EdgeSingular do not contain the rstyle property.
Within cytoscape.js, rstyle is defined with comments "properties for style sent from the renderer to the core" perhaps rstyle is reserved for Cytoscape core functionality.

rstyle property on the edge containing useful values.

```
rstyle: {
  arrowWidth: 13.173844266438728
  bezierPts: null
  clean: true
  dirtyEvents: null
  haystackPts: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  labelAngle: -1.5707963267948966
  labelAutoAngle: 0
  labelHeight: 128
  labelWidth: 386
  labelX: 47.25
  labelY: 0
  linePts: null
  midX: 47.25
  midY: 0
  sourceLabelAngle: -1.5707963267948966
  sourceLabelHeight: 0
  sourceLabelWidth: 0
  srcX: undefined
  srcY: undefined
  targetLabelAngle: -1.5707963267948966
  targetLabelAutoAngle: -0
  targetLabelHeight: 16
  targetLabelWidth: 256
  targetLabelX: 74.5
  targetLabelY: 0
  tgtX: undefined
  tgtY: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t recommend building your app by using private, undocumented fields. Use the public functions in the API like ele.boundingBox() or ele.numericStyle()